# そのまま and parts of speech

Tags: usage, adverbs

こんにちは、、、

私はこの文が分かりますが、文法を考えてみると、はっきり分からなくなります。

> 「北斗七星のひしゃくのえの部分を、そのまま曲がり具合に沿って伸ばしていきます」

二つの動詞、二つの副詞が見えます。「曲がり具合に」と「沿って」はペアです。「そのまま」は、「伸ばして」とペアになりますか？

そうなら、「北斗七星のひしゃくのえの部分を、そのまま伸ばしていきます」と言ったら、同じイメージですか？

よろしくおねがいします（＾＿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

はい、「曲がり具合に」と「沿って」が対応し、「そのまま」と「伸ばして」が対応しています。

なので、「曲がり具合に沿って」がなくても文法的には問題ありません。しかし意味は曖昧になってしまいます。「そのまま伸ばしていく」だけでは、直線的に延長するのか曲線として延長するのか不明瞭だからです。

[image]

Comment: 図が明確で好きです。ありがとうございます！！